# How to give auth condition in laravel 5 middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a middleware that called with `Frontend`, the usage of that middleware is showing menu that i create with [laravel-menu](https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Menu;
use App\Module as modelmodule;
use auth;
class Frontend
{

   public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
         Menu::make('sidebar', function($menu){ 
             $menu->add('Main Menu',array('class' =>  'header'));
                //USER//
                $menu->add("User Control",array('nickname' => "user",'class'=>'treeview'))
                    ->append(' <b class="caret"></b>')
                    ->prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ');
                 $menu->user->add('Daftar User','user/list');
                 $menu->user->add('Tipe User','user/type');
                //Product//
                 $menu->add("Product",array('nickname' => "product",'class'=>'treeview'))
                    ->append(' <b class="caret"></b>')
                    ->prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> ');
                 $menu->product->add('Product List','user/list');
                 //About//
                $menu->add("About Us",array('nickname' => "about"))

                    ->prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> ');

         });
          return $next($request);
 //    }
   }    
}
```

so, my question is how to add `auth condition` for example

```
 if(auth()->user()->isDeveloper()) { 
          $menu->add("About Us",array('nickname' => "about"))
         ->prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> ');
}
```

but my script above with `auth` didn't working. I get this error

> Call to a member function isDeveloper() on null

and here is my user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','type','subscribestatus','usercode'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function isDeveloper()
    {
        return ($this->type == 'TP001');
    }

}
```

how can fix the error ? sorry for my bad english .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the user is logged in before attempting to call a function on it:

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->isDeveloper()) {
```

Comment: already did that. But, I have login in two browsers with different user type. Both of them didn't show the menu with the condition

Comment: @YVS1102 If the error doesn't happen anymore, then the problem is something else. Perhaps the `isDeveloper()` flag is not working correctly.